# Creating text boxes dynamically and adding them to a to a TabControl

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I am using the following code to create text boxes at run time and it's working perfectly:

```
  MarginTextbox.Name = "mid" & id
  MarginLabel.Name = "ML" & id
  MarginTextbox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 10, Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
  MarginLabel.Location = New Point(15, (80 + (counter * 24)))
  MarginTextbox.Location = New Point(110, (80 + (counter * 24)))
  MarginLabel.BackColor = Me.BackColor
  MarginTextbox.Size = New Size(56, 20)
  MarginLabel.Size = New Size(150, 20)
  MarginTextbox.AutoSize = False
  MarginLabel.Text = "Supplier " & id
  Controls.Add(MarginTextbox)
  Controls.Add(MarginLabel)
```

I don't want to place them on the form, but rather in a TabControl tab. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TabControl contains one or more TabPage.
The TabPage has a Controls object collection that can be used to add your textboxes.

So (supposing you have added a TabControl named tabControl1):

```
Dim tp as TabPage = tabControl1.TabPages(0) ' 0 is the index of the page required'
tp.Controls.Add(MarginTextbox)
tp.Controls.Add(MarginLabel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the controls to your `Form`'s `Controls`, add it to your `TabPage`'s `Controls`:

```
Controls.Add(MarginTextbox)
Controls.Add(MarginLabel)
Me.TabPageWhatever.Controls.Add(MarginTextbox)
Me.TabPageWhatever.Controls.Add(MarginLabel)
```

Comment: +1 I forget always that the tabpages are already defined as controls themselves